# Delphi XE3 - is there an easy way to set version info for multiple .dproj files at once?

Tags: xml, delphi, xsd, msbuild, delphi-xe3

I am maintaining a system that consists of more than 2 hundred Delphi applications.

Now I would like to set the same version info (product version, description etc) for all of them. There is the option sets feature that allows for having the same compilation options, but it does not include the version info.

Do you know of any tool that allows for that? I could easy write it since the schema for .dproj files is installed within the .NET framework, but if there is such tool I would like to not open a doors that are already opened.

Comment: my issue is more about setting version info **before** compilation, in multiple XML files, not about setting it for binarires

Comment: That question wants to set the version info before compilation. However, it's a mugs game trying to do this with the IDE. The IDE's version UI is for toy projects. For real production software, you need to script this.

Comment: Use [Dev Extensions](http://andy.jgknet.de/blog/ide-tools/ddevextensions/).  I have been using it since D2007 and it works with all the XEs